# How add UIView to a View as a Subview (for giving user feedback)

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm creating a rate-a-fish application. When the user rates the fish, I want to display a little box which says "Average rating: *** " with stars.

I have achieved something similar in cells for a table, but can't seem to get it to work in a normal view (I run the following code and nothing appears in the view):

```
-(void)displayAvg:(NSInteger)avg{
    UILabel *text = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 90, 20)];
    text.text = @"Average Rating:";

    UIView *wrapper = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 30)];
    wrapper.layer.cornerRadius = 8;
    wrapper.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    [wrapper addSubview:text];
    [text release];

    UIImageView *star;
    NSInteger ratingI = avg;

    for(int i = 0; i<ratingI; i++) {
        star = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"little_star.png"]];
        star.frame = CGRectMake(50 + (i * 16), 0, 16, 16);
        [wrapper addSubview:star];
        [star release];
    }

    [self.view addSubview:wrapper];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:wrapper];
    NSLog(@"Sleeping...");
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];

    [wrapper removeFromSuperview];
    [wrapper release];
}
```

Comment: Does not look bad to me. What is happening? Have you tried stepping through your code with the debugger?

Comment: i think that the problem is here: **[self.view addSubview:wrapper];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:wrapper];**
Check if your view is on window;(check the delegate of rootViewController)

Comment: [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3]; blocks current thread so view is added but blocking thread prevents it from drawing. When 3 seconds are up, view is instantly removed. Get to know NSObject class methods because you'll need them often.

Comment: @TheBlack You are right. Thanks all for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this code The problem is with the following line

```
 [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:3];
```

So instead of this line, you write a new method and call it with 'wrapper' as argument to remove the wrapper view.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(removeWrapper:) withObject:wrapper afterDelay:3];
```

implement the method

```
-(void)removeWrapper:(id)sender
{
    UIView *wrapper = sender;
    [wrapper removeFromSuperview];
    [wrapper release];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't answer to your question but I think it will be better to add timer that will fire in 3 seconds and then remove the window; you will not block the thread this way; Have you tried to add just simple sub view at first, i.e. wrapper with no other code? does it appear then? Or actually as I rethink the problem it might be the answer to your question - blocking thread this way might be the cause the window never get displayed. So far I know UI will be updated after thread returns to the run-loop.

Comment: Yeah you are right but giving the right answer to Arun for going the extra effort of writing the code. Thanks